# Create same folders in different subdirectories in R

Tags: r, directory-structure, create-directory

I try to create the same folders in multiple subdirectories in R. I thought I could do this with a for loop, but it did not go as planned

My folder structure is like this: Main directory/Weather_day . Weather_day contains the folders D0 and D1. I want to create the folders weather and temperature in both D0 and D1

It tried to do it like this with a for loop

```
pathway = "./Weather_day"
for (i in pathway){
    setwd(i)
    dir.create("weather")
    dir.create("temperature")
}
```

However, the outcome of this is that it creates the folders in the main directory folder. Furthermore, I cannot run this code twice or more because it changes the working directory.

Any solutions for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where the `create.dir` function come from? It's package name is ?

Comment: Made a mistake in writing the code here. It is supposed to be dir.create() which is as far as I know part of the standard R functions

Comment: I am a bit confused about about the folder names D0 and D1 and the naming in the code with weather and temperature. Can you explain this?

Comment: @Albin of course. So D0 and D1 stands for on what day the measurements are. They are separate folders. What I want to do is to create in both folders new subdirectories which are called temperature (where I will put in the files with the temperature of the day) and weather (where I will put the files that says whether it rains, sun, snow etc.). I just want to have a R code that creates this for me. Because I do not know what amount of folders are (day 0 until I do not know when) I want to create a for loop that creates these folders without keeping in mind the length of the amount of folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the Weather_day folder is already created. According to your comment my suggestion is as follows.

Furthermore a function also provides additional use, for example if in future you have an additional folder you can simply add it with the function.

```
wd = getwd()

pathway = paste0(wd,"/Weather_day/")

dir.create(pathway)
    
create_dir = function (x) {
  for (i in x){
    if(!dir.exists(paste0(pathway, i))){dir.create(paste0(pathway, i))}
  }}


create_dir(c("weather","temperature"))
```

I checked the code and with the if statement you prevent overwriting existing folders which I highly suggest. But it depends on the use case.

**Edit**

Regarding your comment I adjusted my suggestion. I am not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for:

```
pathway = paste0(getwd(),"/Weather_day/")

d = c("D0","D1")
x = c("weather", "temperature")

create_dir = function (d, x) {
  for (i in d){
    if(!dir.exists(paste0(pathway, i))){dir.create(paste0(pathway, i))}
  for (j in x){
    if(!dir.exists(paste0(pathway, i, "/", j))){dir.create(paste0(pathway, i, "/", j))}
  }}}

create_dir(d,x)
```

With the code above you get each of the folders weather and temperature in folder D0 and D1.

Comment: I tried this code, but it makes a new folder which is called Weather_day in the main directory and put the new folders "weather" and "temperature" in there. However, I already have a folder Weather_day and in there I have right now the subdirectories Day 0 and Day1. I want to create the weather and temperature folders in both these subdirectories so in both D0 and D1.

Comment: I also tried to edit some of the code by removing the creation of the getwd () and use the pathway like I did it previously created, but then it creates the folders in the Weather_day folder and not in D0 and D1

Comment: @alexdegrote1995 Okay, I see. I just had to create the Weather_day in my directories that I was able to reproduce the results. I edited my answer, hopefully this brings you closer to your solution. Else let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You should loop through all sub directories. Yous `"./Weather_day"` is not enough.

```
setwd("./Weather_day")
pathway <- list.files(full.names = F)
for (i in pathway){
    dir.create(paste0(i,"/weather"))
    dir.create(paste0(i,"/temperature"))
}
```

The directory tree situation before and after:
Before

```
weather_day
├── D0
└── D1
```

After

```
weather_day
├── D0
│  ├── temperature
│  └── weather
└── D1
   ├── temperature
   └── weather
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I get a warning that says : cannot create dir 'D0\weather', reason 'No such file or directory'. What is the problem here

Comment: To see my updated answer. I suppose you are in your main directory.